# I am trying to practice for sql using pgadmin with northwind database please check images for what i am trying to do

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

[enter image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqO61.png)description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g62jB.png)

please help me out

i tried to restart the pgadmin also tried other column from same table nothing worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you have used upper and lower case in the definition of the field name:

```
SELECT "LastName" FROM employees;
```

Try to make clear questions and put the sentences in the message body. Isn't a good practice put a printscreen.

Greetings, Alejandro